# FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX is deleted from Imgproc class in JAVA

Tags: java, opencv, intellij-idea, fonts, face-recognition

I'm working on a face recognition project using `opencv` and `opencv contrib` libraries, and when I do run my code, it gives me this error :

```
  java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
  location: class org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc
```

and when I search into the `Imgproc` class I discovered that `FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX` field didn't include in the class !!
Please if can you help me !!

Comment: "run my code". What code ?

Answer (score 0):

The location of this depends on the version of opencv you are using. For example, in version 3.4 it can be found in `org.opencv.core.Core` [(documented here)](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/javadoc/org/opencv/core/Core.html#FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX), and in version 4.2 it can be found in the class you are expecting it [(documented here)](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/javadoc/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html)

Since you are presumably following instructions based on a later version I suggest you use version 4.2 at least.